# How to achieve a rounded border with a header inside the border with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm still learning a lot about HTML and CSS and web development in general. I'm working on this site for a friend and I'm using HTML5, CSS3 and Bootstrap 4 for the site. I have a mockup designed in photoshop and I'm currently trying to figure out the best way to recreate a portion of it. This is the portion:

[image: rounded-outline]

So I'm not sure the best way to do this, a slightly rounded border with the heading as it is. I know how to do a rounded border (using border-radius), I'm just not sure the best way to add this header. Is this better done as an SVG or can I get it done with CSS and HTML?

Comment: it would be good if you post code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated before Fieldset with legend is the most straight-forard example

```css
fieldset {
 width:700px;
  height:300px;
  border:2px solid #ccc;
  position:relative;
   /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
  -moz-border-radius: 8px; 
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
  border-radius: 8px; 
}

legend {
 font-size:1.4rem;
  margin-left:5px;
}

fieldset img {
  max-width:200px;
  max-height:300px;
}

fieldset h1.header {
color:#AE8193;
  font-size:2.0rem;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

fieldset .text {
  float:right;
  width:70%;
}

fieldset .text a.readmore {
  color:#AE8193;
  text-decoration:underline;
  font-size:1.0pt;
  font-size:1.0rem;
}

.clearfix {
  clear:both;
  height:15px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>Up This Week</legend>

 <img src="http://www.loraccosmetics.com/storeimages/Images/2014-Summer/LORAC-Alter-Ego-Group-medium.jpg" />
  <div class="text">
    <h1 class="header">Title Text</h1>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <a href="#" class="readmore">Read More</a>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a good old fashioned `fieldset`, the `Legend` will show in the border.

You can add a `border-radius:5px` to slightly round the corners.

I've styled up a very quick mock up of what you want below.

```css
.img{
width:70px;
height:70px;
background-color:blue;
float:left
}

fieldset{
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>

<legend>Up This Week</legend>

<div class="img"></div>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc volutpat lorem nec sapien sagittis convallis. Praesent rhoncus a lacus quis semper. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas et sapien enim.

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided us with, I can give you a hint - take a look at `<fieldset>` [tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset). The part of mockup you showed here can be done like this:

```css
fieldset {
    border-radius: .5em;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px #ddd solid;
}
fieldset > p, fieldset > h1 {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 111px;
}
fieldset h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
fieldset > p + p {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
  <fieldset>
   <legend>de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum</legend>
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ4UXkL7-MovU2Y1cXlUhg9uZECINIqU8aXjNur9Xm12N93qYBA" align="left">
   <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p><a href="https://www.lipsum.com/" target=_blank">more</a></p>
  </fieldset>
```

Other options include [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform?v=a) (translate) where you initially have kinda normal markup and then just elevate the caption.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a title and flex to draw the two bits of the top border:

```css
img{
position:absolute;
left:20px;
top:20px;
bottom:20px;
width:15%;
height:calc(100% - 40px);
object-fit:cover;
}

div{
box-sizing:border-box;
position:relative;
margin-top:2em;
border:3px solid gray;
border-top:none;
border-radius:5px;
}
div p {
margin:0.5em;
padding-left:calc(15% + 40px);
padding-bottom:20px;
}
h1 {
display:flex;transform:translatey(-0.7em);
margin:0;
}
h1:before,
h1:after
{
box-sizing:border-box;
content:'';
height:0.5em;
margin-top:auto;
border-top:3px solid gray;
}
h1:before {margin-right:0.5em;
padding-left:1em;}
h1:after {margin-left:0.5em;
flex:1;}
```

```html
<div>

<h1>Up This Week</h1>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/220/nature"/>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc volutpat lorem nec sapien sagittis convallis. Praesent rhoncus a lacus quis semper. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas et sapien enim.</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc volutpat lorem nec sapien sagittis convallis. Praesent rhoncus a lacus quis semper. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas et sapien enim.</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc volutpat lorem nec sapien sagittis convallis. Praesent rhoncus a lacus quis semper. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas et sapien enim.</p>

</div>
```

Use your own layout style for the text and image content, it is **out of subject** and here for the demo and the curiiosity of `object-fit` to clip image if needed.